# $\lim(a_n)\rightarrow 0$, $\lim(b_n)\rightarrow$ no limit, $a_nb_n\rightarrow 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, examples-counterexamples

Find a sequence $a_n$ such that its $\lim(a_n)\rightarrow 0$ and $b_n$ that $\lim(b_n)$ has no limit (finite or infinite) such that $\lim(a_nb_n)\rightarrow1$

using arithmetic i need to find a sequence $a_n$ and $(a_n)^{-1}$.

let say $a_n$=$\frac{1}{n}$ what $b_n$ I need to choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sequence $a_n = n^{1/n}$ tends to $1$ instead of $0$ as you want.

Try the following sequence pair instead: $$a_n=1/n \text{ and } b_n=n$$

Another example:

$$a_n = (-1)^n/n \text{ and }b_n=(-1)^n n$$

Comment: yes I edited $a_n$ but $b_n=n$ has a limit (infinite)

Comment: @gbox $b_n$ has no limit. If you want $b_n$ not to properly diverge to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, try the second example.

Comment: I need $b_n$ like $(-1)^n$, sorry I am new to calculus how does it called?

Comment: @gbox See the second example, I have added in my post. Usually, when you say that the limit doesn't exist, this means the sequences are allowed to properly diverge to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. (In fact, even in your post you seem to indicate that: "...has no limit (finite or infinite) such that..."

Comment: Thanks! that what I was looking for, so saying "...has no limit (finite or infinite) such that..." is wrong terminology?

Comment: @gbox Typically, no limit includes the case when the limit is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. Again it depends on what convention you want to follow.